# How to call Windows background service in Blazor(.net6) web application?

Tags: c#, blazor, signalr, .net-6.0, background-service

How do I consume windows background service in my Blazor .net 6 web application.

I have created two projects, one is a background service and it is running on my machine and another is a Blazor web application. So How do I call running windows service in my web application?

Comment: **Exactly** what kind of interaction with the Windows Service are you thinking of? A Windows Service is the Win32 equivalent of a *nix daemon: it's just a userland process that runs - there is no requirement it offer any kind of API to other processes running in the same box.

Comment: Your blazor web application runs on the client/browser and the server, from which side do you want to call the Windows service?
You can't call a local service from inside a browser! that violates the whole browser principle and internet security.
Technically you can call a Windows service from a web application running on a server but that is highly suspicious and not conventional

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its generally not a good idea to "call a windows service" directly. If you want your background service to respond to web requests it should be hosted in IIS or kestrel, and called like a regular api. This is idea if you expect a response from your request. Otherwise I would suggest using a message broker such as [rabbit mq](https://www.rabbitmq.com/) to dispatch a request. Ideally the message would be sent by an endpoint exposed with your blazor app.

Comment: There’s no need to add a dependency on RabbitMQ when Windows has its own dependable MSMQ built-in: https://stackoverflow.com/q/400115/159145

Comment: @Dai True. I never said "must use rabbit", just "use a message broker such as..." but I would never use MSMQ for a production build.

Comment: May I ask what your reservations about MSMQ are?